# Teachers (of/from) various schools met to discuss how to improve the standard of English

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

**Teachers *(of/from)* various schools met to discuss how to improve the standard of English.**

Which word should be used here, *of* or *from*?

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct but have different meanings.

1. > Teachers *of* various schools met to discuss how to improve the
   >   standard of English.

   Means English teachers who follow different *systems* or *styles*
   of English teaching met.  *School* here means:

   > > A group of persons who hold a common doctrine or follow the same teacher (as in philosophy, theology, or medicine) <*the
   > >     Aristotelian school*>;  Also:  the doctrine or practice of such a
   > >     group.   - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/school)
2. > Teachers *from* various schools met to discuss how to improve the
   >   standard of English.

   Means English teachers from different *campuses* met.

Comment: Very nice; upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**From** is the correct usage.
It is refers to the origin, here the Teachers are from various school(place of origin )